# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac 4x\right)^{\frac x8}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluate $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac 4x\right)^{\frac x8}$

I think the end result is $1^\infty$, so the answer is undefined?

Comment: Hint: are you familiar with the limit definition of $e^x$?

Comment: $1^{\infty}$ is an _indeterminate form_. What this means is precisely that knowing $\lim f(x)=1$ and $\lim g(x)=\infty$, you cannot say anything about $\lim \left(f(x)^{g(x)}\right)$ just using this fact alone. Don't confuse 'indeterminate' with 'undefined'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac 4x\right)^{\frac x8}=$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \exp\left(\frac{1}{8}x\ln\left(1+\frac{4}{x}\right)\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{4}{x}\right)}{\frac{8}{x}}\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{2(x+4)}\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{2}\right)=$$
$$e^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{e}$$

Answer (score 10):

One of the definitions of $e^y$ is $\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1+\dfrac{y}x\right)^x$. I trust you can conclude from this.

Comment: Oh, you were faster, I thought the same. :)

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** You can use the fact, that $e^x$ is the $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\dfrac{x}n\right)^n$

Answer (score 2):

What you can also do is to write out the following, $$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} (1+ \frac{4}{x})^\frac{x}{8} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}  e^{\ln \left(  (1+ \frac{4}{x})^\frac{x}{8} \right)}  = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}  e^{\frac{x}{8} ln( 1 + \frac{4}{x})} = e^{ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{8} ln( 1 + \frac{4}{x})}  $$
because $e^x$ is continuous. Now all we need is to determine the following limit and plug it into $e^x$, $$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{8} \ln (1 + 4/x)  $$
From L'hopitals rule, the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$. So the answer we are looking for is $\sqrt{e}$.